# Are there connectors designed to be placed radially at a right angle to the cable?

Tags: connector

I have some constrained grommets I would like to run a 5-pin shielded sensor wire through. The sensor and wire will be removed after the tests are done, so running bare wire through and afterwards placing connectors on the end is not an option.

This got me to thinking that what I would like to do is take a connector like a JST and wire the connector up such that it is installed lengthwise along the wire, barely expanding the wire's width. This will pass easily through the grommets, without unduly stressing the individual wires. (Of course, there are other ways to solve this problem, but I'm in particular interested in this approach for my personal edification, esp. because if there's a technique which can be broadly applied then it's a useful tool to teach to my EE students.)

I feel like I've seen plenty of automotive connectors which turn 90 degrees inside a housing, but I can't think if I've ever seen one where the wires themselves are somehow crimped such that they make a 90 degree angle with the housing.

Does such a thing exist? I'm sure it must, but my search skills are obviously not up to the task. The closest I've found is a perpendicular splice:

[image]

---

##### Update:

I've been asked for a picture, so here's the best I can think of:

[image]

In red is how big the connector PLUS 90 degree bend is. It can be made shorter by mashing wires, but that extreme bend radius is not great for the wires. In blue is how big the connector itself is, and it's relevant to note that it is on the same scale as the wire bundle. So as the connector gets more pins, the size hole it can fit through when rotated radially stays constant. It would be nice to find a clever wiring technique or connector which can be employed to create the 90-degree radial bend without mashing wires.

Comment: Please provide more info: What is the ID of the Grommet? Do you want a cable-to-cable connector or a cable-to-PCB connector?

Comment: Is it acceptable to replace the grommet with a panel-mounted circular connector?

Comment: Why are you talking about a 90 degree connector? How is the second part of your question (90 degree)  related with the first part (passing a  connector through a small round hole)? I don't see how they are related. Draw a sketch.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I updated the question with a rudimentary picture. I hope it conveys the idea.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Re replacing the grommet, "no" for two reasons. The first "no" is because the particular problem is on a certificated normal airplane, so there's no ability to swap things out, no matter how much sense that might make. The second "no" is because I'm hoping to learn about a broad class of EE which I've heretofore been ignorant of, so simply solving an immediate problem wouldn't get me far down that road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your description why you necessarily need to bend the cables 90°, but want an narrow "in-line connector". Unless I'm missing something, here's an option you may have overlooked in its ubiquity:

[image: Illustration of different headphone connectors]

<sup>From [EarbudsZone](https://www.earbudszone.com/headphones-jacks-plugs/)</sup>

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know that you could get as many as 5 connectors. I would say that it solves a certain class of X/Y problem, but it's nowhere near as compact as the cables are. The example JST connector sideways can be pushed laterally through much narrower holes, and it can have many more than 5 pins.

Comment: I take it back, with the use of flexPCB those can get really, really small. https://www.ebay.com/itm/154010765798 This might be a general class of answer to my question, since the connector is quite a 90-degree rotation about the desired axis. @DavideAndrea linked to https://rampartproducts.com/home/our-products/rotary-fit-hpht/, which shows that this approach can reasonably push past 5 connectors.

Answer (score 2):

> wire the connector up such that it is installed lengthwise along the wire, barely expanding the wire's width.

Here are some small-diameter circular connectors (my site):

- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=inline_contact_conn
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=nano_plastic_circ_conn

Answer (score 0):

> Are there connectors designed to be placed radially at a right angle to the cable?

> I can't think if I've ever seen one where the wires themselves are somehow crimped such that they make a 90 degree angle with the housing.

I have. For example (my site):

- [Molex SolderRight board-in terminals](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=board_in_to_pcb_wire_terminals&s=SolderRight)
- [Board-in crimp plugs with 90 degree pins](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=board_in_crimp_plugs&s=35023)
- [Board-in PCB headers with IDT termination](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=board_in_idt_plugs&s=DD%20DS)
- [Parallel mate connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=parallel_mate_w2b_conn)
- [Single-wall connector with IDT termination](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=single_wall_conn_4&&fl=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000-c04-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C)
- [IDC bump connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=prismatic_bump_idc_conn)
- [Hirose DF9M rectangular connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=misc_gen_purp_rect_conn&s=DF9M%20-%20DF9%20(w2b))

Comment: https://connectorbook.com/ is your site??? Cue "I'm not worthy meme"! It's down for the moment, but I'll be sure to give it a look once it's back up.

Comment: Hmmm, unless turned sideways, or only have a contact or two, all of those connectors would fail to pass through a hole which is comparably sized to the wires.